# How to do the PCA on huge sparse dataset

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have sparse dataset contains 43600 features and 414800 samples.
I want to reduce the dimensions to 50 features only.The data will be 414800*50 as output and also the coefficient, the score and the mu of the PCA will be obtained.
I cannot use the regular PCA matlab function since it is sparse dataset and I cannot do it manually with for or parfor loop because it is time consuming and didn't finish running.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the covariance matrix of your input dataset, and convert it to a dense matrix, which would be a  43600 * 43600  matrix in your case. Assuming S is you input 414800 * 43600 sparse matrix, this would be like:

```
Smul=full(S.'*S);
Sm=full(mean(S));
Sm2=414800 *Sm.'*Sm;
Scov=Smul-Sm2;
```

Apply eigs function on the covariance matrix to obtain the first 50 dominant eigenvectors,

```
[V,D] = eigs(Scov,50);
```

And obtain pcs by projecting the zero centered matrix on eigenvectors,

```
Sr=(S-Sm)*V;
```

Sr is the reduced dimension version of S.